# How to reverse-multiply signed division bytearray in java?

Tags: java, arrays, division, unsigned

I have a bytearray like this:

```
byte[] bArr = new byte[]{(byte) -19, (byte) -78, (byte) -25, (byte) -68, (byte) -56, (byte) -31, (byte) 4, (byte) 9]
```

if I do a multiply, example: `bArr[i] = bArr[i] * 3`, now i got a new bytearray. But is there anyway to get back bArr? I tried to use `/` and `Integer.unsignedDivision()` but failed.

Comment: what do u mean by "now i got a new bytearray"

Comment: `(byte) -78 * 3` ... underflow? Signed byte ranges from `-128 ... 128`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But is there anyway to get back bArr?*

**No.** Unless, you had created one temporary array and copied the content of  `bArr` before performing stated operation. Moreover, `bArr[i] * 3` operation may lead to underflow/overflow problem in your new array.